# Chrome extension – "Cannot read property 'onMessage' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

#### Creating a Chrome extension.

Part of the extension is to get the current tab URL.

The only way I've found of doing so is by putting the script in `background.js` and having an event listener in `script.js`

Except that's what I thought... I've been all over Google, StackOverflow, apparently everything points to same answer of putting the script in `background.js` and having an event listener in `script.js` but I keep getting `Cannot read property 'onMessage' of undefined`

The code below doesn't work because it gets the Chrome ext url, not the current tab url

```
current_url = window.location.href
console.log(current_url)
```

Below is what I currently have:

#### background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(sender.tab ?
                    "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                    "from the extension");
        if (request.greeting === "hello")
        sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
    }
    );
```

#### script.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(sender.tab ?
                    "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                    "from the extension");
        if (request.greeting === "hello")
        sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
    }
    );
```

#### manifest.js

```
{
  "name": "Getting Started Example",
  "description": "Build an Extension!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting", "bookmarks", "tabs"],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
  },
  "options_page": "options.html"
}
```

Comment: It's unclear where exactly you want to get the URL. If it's inside popup.html then just use chrome.tabs.query in your popup.js that you load in popup.html via `<script src=popup.js></script>`.